# Trying to test my python library, it's installed but not found

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install my library locally and test it, it shows up as installed:

```
PS C:\Projects\pypi\potatoutils> pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///C:/Projects/pypi/potatoutils
Installing collected packages: potatoutils
  Attempting uninstall: potatoutils
    Found existing installation: potatoutils 0.0.1
    Uninstalling potatoutils-0.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled potatoutils-0.0.1
  Running setup.py develop for potatoutils
Successfully installed potatoutils
```

But when I try to test it

```
PS C:\Projects\pypi\potatoutils> python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import potatoutils
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'potatoutils'
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: pip and python have the same version (3.7) and their paths match.

And the library shows up when I use pip list.

Comment: can you `pip list` after you installed potatoutils check if it's there?

Comment: potatoutils         0.0.1      c:\projects\pypi\potatoutils

yes, it's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to get the library up and running by starting over and following these instructions:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-create-a-python-library-7d5aea80cc3f
I still don't know what went wrong the first time (maybe outdated instructions?) but it no longer matters to me.

Answer (score 0):

Often this is the issue if you pip install a package with pip for python2.x
but then when you attempt to import your library for python3.x

Make sure you're running installing pip packages for the correct python version.

Comment: The pip package is for the correct version and the paths match.

Answer (score 0):

use pip3 using pip sometimes point to python 2.x versions, that's why maybe it can help!

Comment: Already tried that, it didn't work. Thanks for trying anyway!